# Which user has installed an Android App?

Tags: android, google-account, installed-applications

When an user installs an Android App from Google Play, he/she has to login with a Google Account: does exists an Android API for getting which Google Account has been used for the App installation?

I would like to sell my App from Google Play, but I would give to the buyer a free trial period. I can't use subscriptions because they require a recurring payment (monthly or yearly), whereas I would set a una-tantum price.
When the trial period expire, I can use a non-consumable In-app product, but how can I manage the trial period?
Both Google Play Licensing and In-app Billing track purchase information on a per-user basis, thus they should be able to know which user has downloaded the App or who is the current user, and I too would like to know the same info in order to manage the trial period by means my web server.
If someone of you can suggest another way, I appreciate.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let the user connect to his google account in your app. Then the app can save the first user who logged on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API to include in your app's code to keep record of user who have downloaded your app from Play Store. However before you upload your app to Play Store , you have to create a Developers account.

There google have provided Developer Console option, and this is where you will find download information for your app.